# Newton JSON.NET ignores json attributes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to serialize object loaded from external DLL with reflection.
The object is serialized ignoring any existing json attributes like: JsonObject, JsonProperty, JsonConverter.

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllpath);    
object result = [invoke method on external assembly]
var json = JObject.FromObject(result, new JsonSerializer { 
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        });
```

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` doesn't work too.

Comment: Is there any for your to give a [mcve] for your problem?  Is there any chance the external DLL is using a different version of Json.NET?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the external DLL and myself used different versions of Newtonsoft.JSON
When I downgraded Newtonsoft version to 7.0.3 it started working.

Comment: If you want to use the new version you should be able to use a assembly binding redirect to upgrade the external assembly.  I beleive Newtonsoft tries to avoid breaking changes.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx